# Cargo fails to build termbox-sys on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

[image: cmd]

[image: toml]

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: It would be better to add the information as text rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Rustbox doesn't seem to support Windows yet:  https://github.com/gchp/rustbox/issues/7 , though someone [has previously worked on it](https://github.com/jayrandez/rustbox/tree/win-dev).